# How to build custom colour builder functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I am working on a functionality where admin user can change CSS(basically colours) of various sections of user facing app through his admin panel.Please refer to the sample screenshot below.

[image: Site builder sample]

The colours he change will be immediately reflected in the **screenshot** kind of image with a smaller width and height than actual, to visualise in the admin screen.

I have two approaches for this

1. **Screenshot as a html**  - I can copy paste the html contents of the user app and put it in a admin page but don't this its a very good approach
2. **Screenshot as a iframe** - I can load the contents in iframe separately and access the iframe contents to change the css[Same origin, so no CORS issue] but the issue with this is I am not able to access the DOM itself as app was developed with a react library, so there is no real DOM.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: There is always a real DOM, the one you see rendered right now on your screen.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides. So how do you access the real DOM within an iframe? Simple tricks like
`$("#myframe").load(function() {
  var content =document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument;
    })`  not returning the real DOM

Comment: Even the browser page source doesn't give you the parsed DOM.Why it is so?