# How to access the actual react rendered DOM in another application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-dom, html-imports

I have a use case where I need to render the react app in another app(User app preview in admin app case like scenario).Both the apps are from same origin but different repositories and different tech. Also I don't need the javascript functions only HTML and CSS would be suffice for this

I tried using [html imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) like

```
<link rel="import" href="http://example.com" />
```

and iframe like this

```
<iframe  src="http://example.com"></iframe>
$("#myframe").load(function() {
        var slide =document.getElementById("myframe").contentDocument;

    })
```

both gives me the same kind of DOM output while accessing

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Although with Iframe its rendered properly in an iframe, the only issue is I am not able to access the DOM.

I understand its because react app is always rendered at client side but I want to get the rendered DOM.So how can I access the actual rendered DOM?

Even i noticed that even page source in a browser doesn't give the rendered DOM? Why doesn't it show you the rendered DOM?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are *really* trying to accomplish, but what is clear is that you are trying to use ReactJs in a scenario it isn't designed for.  Accessing/modifying the DOM directly is counter to every principle React is designed around.

Comment: @Claies In a nutshell, I need to enable a user app preview functionality which is in react into the admin app which is in rails.

Comment: I'm still confused.  You want the server (rails) to render the client (react) DOM, and then have rails modify that DOM somehow?  This seems backwards.

Comment: No, the admin app is with full stack rails( including views) and there is a user app which is completely different (with react and rails).There is no relation between two apps except its from same origin. I need to design  user app preview in admin app

Comment: it still sounds like you are trying to force something to happen that wasn't designed to happen.  You aren't really explaining why you think you need to access the DOM of the rendered app, and beyond that, if you think you need to manipulate the DOM, you are probably missing the point of ReactJs completely.  React uses a Shadow DOM to control how updates are rendered, which is why the original DOM is basically empty.

Comment: Hi @Claies . This is what I want to do exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148440/how-to-build-custom-colour-builder-functionality

Comment: so you asked the same question in a slightly different way hoping you would get an answer?  The answer is still the same.... The only way to modify the rendered DOM is to access the Shadow DOM, through React, but if you are doing this, you are doing something wrong.  If you want the react app to change colors, then expose those colors as props, design the react app to respond to those props, and then set those props on your app entry point.

Answer (score 1):

if JS functionality and events are not required, then use ReactDOMServer.renderToString

```
 import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
```

--

```
 this.setState({html:ReactDomServer.renderToString(<Component/>});
```

this gives the html as a string.

after which set html dangerously into a div

```
 <div id="comp" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.html }} />
```

once this is done you have the DOM elemets but **no functionality**. Just DOM elements for you to display. (CSS is included);

readup here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html

Comment: Sounds like a good approach but the app in which it has be rendered is rails app. The app which is to be rendered is react app so not sure how to take this approach to rails

Comment: what is your web server? Apache? node?

Comment: Apache web server

Comment: I had sent up a node server to serve me this html. but its not possible for you

Comment: check this out Serverside rendering using rails https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Although you answer makes sense but I am trying to implement the other way around i.e. to generate different static page for the preview while building itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166502/discussion-between-sujit-warrier-and-aman-jagga).